Not be able to deploy in dedicated inference endpoint for phi3 vision model
while try to deploy i am facing issue like custom model error need to set trust_remote_code = "True". Anyone here help me to sort this problem
2024/08/02 22:48:58
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/auto/configuration_auto.py", line 1114, in from_pretrained
2024/08/02 22:48:58
trust_remote_code = resolve_trust_remote_code(
2024/08/02 22:48:58
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/dynamic_module_utils.py", line 611, in resolve_trust_remote_code
2024/08/02 22:48:58
raise ValueError(
2024/08/02 22:48:58
ValueError: The repository for /repository contains custom code which must be executed to correctly load the model. You can inspect the repository content at https://hf.co//repository.
2024/08/02 22:48:58
Please pass the argument `trust_remote_code=True` to allow custom code to be run


What library are you using? Please [edit] to add the tag for it. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for more tips, like how to write a good title.
